# Dynamic methods using define_method and eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eval, dynamic-method, class-eval

I've put together two sample classes implemented in a couple of different ways which pretty well mirrors what I want to do in my Rails model. My concern is that I don't know what, if any are the concerns of using either method. And I've only found posts which explain how to implement them or a general warning to avoid/ be careful when using them. What I have not found is a clear explanation of how to accomplish this safely, and what I'm being careful of or why I should avoid this pattern.

```
class X
  attr_accessor :yn_sc, :um_sc
  def initialize
    @yn_sc = 0
    @um_sc = 0
  end
  types = %w(yn um)
  types.each do |t|
    define_method("#{t}_add") do |val|
      val = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["%s", val])
      eval("@#{t}_sc += #{val}")
    end
  end
end

class X
  attr_accessor :yn_sc, :um_sc
  def initialize
    @yn_sc = 0
    @um_sc = 0
  end
  types = %w(yn um)
  types.each do |t|
    # eval <<-EVAL also works
    self.class_eval <<-EVAL 
      def #{t}_add(val)
        @#{t}_sc += val
      end
    EVAL
  end
end


x = X.new
x.yn_add(1) #=> x.yn_sc == 1 for both
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code looks realy safe. But imagine a code based on user input. It might be look something like

```
puts 'Give me an order, sir!'
order = gets.chomp
eval(order)
```

What will happen if our captain will go wild and order us to `'rm -rf ~/'`? Sad things for sure!

So take a little lesson. `eval` is not safe because it evaluates every string it receives.
But there's another reason **not** to use `eval`. Sometimes it evaluates slower than alternatives. Look [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval) if interested.

Comment: Well, `val` will be user input from a form, although I know there are ways a malicious user can spoof that, hence the `sanitize`.